# Paramiko holds on put command

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to send a zip file to a remote server via sftp but it keeps holding up the script. On windows with a decent connection the file is sent without a problem but on a linux it doesn't work. I've tried raising an exception when the upload finishes but with no luck.

These are the log messages:

```
Jul 28 10:24:40 igt22-dev mqtt.sh[1353]: 46.21875 46.258296966552734
Jul 28 10:24:40 igt22-dev mqtt.sh[1353]: 46.25 46.258296966552734
Jul 28 10:24:40 igt22-dev mqtt.sh[1353]: 46.258296966552734 46.258296966552734
Jul 28 10:24:40 igt22-dev mqtt.sh[1353]: finished
```

and this is the code:

```
    ftp_client = server_client.open_sftp()

    source = "/usr/local/bin/log_history.zip"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/log_history.zip"

    def callback_fun(current, maximum):
        print(current / 1048576, maximum / 1048576)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if current == maximum:
            print("finished")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            raise Exception("finished")


    ftp_client.put(source, destination, callback=callback_fun)
    ftp_client.close()
    print("exited")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Have you tried running the code in a debugger to find out where it hangs? Does it give any output?

Comment: the code provided is everything there is (except for importing paramiko, sys and setting up server connection). As stated in the post every time the code is run on a microcontroller with linux it hangs up but when run on my computer it works fine so somewhat reproducible but fully. I have not tried running it in a debugger since I am limited to working with a console. It does give an output - log messages shown in the post

Comment: Well, just add the missing imports then. I should be able to copy'n'paste it in order to reproduce the issue, at most the paths and the hostname should need tweaking. That said, even on the console, you can use `python -m pdb` to invoke the built-in debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Not a fix but I managed to find a workaround. I run the code in a separate thread and when it finishes i just kill it